Is CRC Calculation Faster on Xilinx Alveo U280 FPGA Using a Custom Algorithm or a Lookup Table?
I am working on a project where I need to implement CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) on a Xilinx Alveo U280 FPGA. I am considering two approaches for CRC calculation and would like to understand which one would be faster in terms of performance:
Custom Algorithm: Implementing the CRC calculation using custom logic that leverages the parallel processing capabilities of the FPGA.
Lookup Table: Precomputing the CRC values for all possible inputs and storing them in a lookup table for quick retrieval.

Here are the details and constraints of my project:
The FPGA model is Xilinx Alveo U280.
The FPGA has a sufficient amount of logic resources and memory.
The data sizes can vary, ranging from small (8-bit) to large (potentially multi-kilobyte streams).
Speed is a critical factor, and I need the CRC computation to be as fast as possible.
Memory usage should be efficient, but I am willing to allocate a reasonable amount of memory for performance gains.

I would appreciate insights on the following points:
Which approach is generally faster for CRC computation on an FPGA, specifically the Xilinx Alveo U280?
How do the two methods compare in terms of scalability and resource usage on this FPGA?
Are there any hybrid approaches or optimizations that could combine the benefits of both methods?
Any advice, examples, or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Why is this question tagged as C++ and HLSL (Microsoft's High-Level Shader Language for DirectX?) Are either of those involved with your question? Also, just as a heads-up, Stack Overflow is generally for computer programming questions. For FPGAs, you might be better served with the Electrical Engineering SE site, as FPGA gateware design is generally very different from computer programming and much more like digital circuit design.

@reirab Yeah, sorry, by HLS, I meant High-level synthesis.

I'm not seeing how they are not both custom logic. Everything in an FPGA is custom logic.
What you might mean by your first alternative would be a classic shift-register implementation, which would process one bit of input per cycle.
For your second alternative you could implement a table-lookup that processes eight bits of input per cycle, with a table that is 256 by the the number of bits in the CRC.
You need to be quantitative about the speed you require. "As fast as possible" is not a valid requirement. Is one bit per cycle fast enough? If not, how about eight? If not that, then what does your application require?

Finally for the lookup table method, how feasible is it to scale this up to handle larger data sizes without excessive memory usage?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method (custom logic vs. lookup table)?The goal is to maximize the number of bits processed per cycle.
Is it possible for a custom algorithm implementation to outperform a table lookup in terms of speed on the U280 FPGA?

Slower with fewer gates, vs. faster with more gates.

Stop saying things like "as fast as possible", and "maximize". How many bits do you need to process per cycle? One? A hundred? A million? You need a number.

I see now. Actually, I am not sure at the moment. I think you are saying that we cannot directly compare these two methods when we are using FPGAs. As long as we use more gates, we can achieve faster performance compared to lookup tables. (Sorry if I sound stupid; I am new to this area.)

@Arash - custom versus table - I'm wondering how native instructions like X86 CRC32 are implemented in hardware, and how these would compare to hardware based table lookup. Maybe Mark Adler would know this.

@Arash Correct. You can keep adding more and more gates, processing more of the data in parallel, increasing the number of bits processed per cycle to as many as you like. There are ways to combine the CRCs from multiple paths to compute the total CRC.

@rcgldr I have not seen a white paper from Intel about the internal implementation of their CRC-32C instruction. If I had to guess, I'd think they would compute a single formula for slamming 64 bits through the shift register in 64 shifts, and generate a minimal set of gates to implement that function in three layers, since the instruction has a latency of three clock cycles, where the layers are pipelined permitting a throughput of one instruction per cycle.

@MarkAdler - It might be implemented as operations in parallel, with 3 clock cycles needed for worst case propagation delay through the ladder of gate logic.

@rcgldr Yes, but it would take far fewer gates to break up the calculation into three pieces, each with a delay of less than one clock, and pipeline them, which is why I would bet on that. Anyway, this is all speculation.
